# Facebook Like button creation is 'bugged' for my website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

OK, weird question. I had a Facebook like button on my website (DealsMatrix.net). I lost my hosting, had to move all my files and what not.

I got new hosting up, and using the same code, the Facebook 'Like' button was not working. I went to the Facebook Dev site (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to create a new one.

**When I put in my website however (http://dealsmatrix.net/) with the www. or not, it shows a blank box. Every other website works for me.**

What do I do?

Comment: You have commented the 'like' div? Also have you registered your new hostname on facebook?

Comment: I commented it out because it was not working and taking up 450px worth of blank space in the design. When you say register my hostname on facebook, where exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You've included the appId in your web page:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=102588413138554";`

which means your current hostname must match the information at https://developers.facebook.com/apps
That's where you first register your website information

But usually a like button can be anywhere so the src could simply be `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";` Check it to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I had almost given up hope. I changed this on my page but to no avail. Still comes up blank.

Comment: remove the data-href attribute, uncomment that div and see if it works. Sometimes that attribute might lead to distraction.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. So after doing this, http://www.dealsmatrix.net/index.php showed the Like button. However, the root domain http://www.dealsmatrix.net/ still shows it as blank. I guess it's better than nothing! I really appreciate all the time you took to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include this in your header:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this with no luck however. Same result. Just blank. I feel like Facebook 'marked' my URL/domain as down or not accessible because the hosting was off for a few months. Maybe that's why? Is there anyway I can 're-ping' their service or something so they know my website is back up and running? Ugh :{